# cv::Mat created from IplImage and reference counting

Tags: c++, opencv

The Mat object uses reference counting, so when the last Mat object is destroyed, the matrix is freed. What happens if we create a `Mat` from an `IplImage*`, however:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("test.png", 1);
{
    Mat mtx(img); // convert IplImage* -> Mat
}
```

Does the `IplImage` hold a reference as well, or would it be left a dangling pointer once the Mat is destroyed?

Comment: avoid using IplImages (as well as c-api functions) at all, please.

Comment: @berak I don't use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat(const%20IplImage*%20img,%20bool%20copyData)), there is a `copyData` parameter for that operator.

```
Mat::Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false)
```

Documentation says the following:

*img – Pointer to the old-style IplImage image structure. By default, the data is shared between the original image and the new matrix. But when copyData is set, the full copy of the image data is created.*

So, if you use `copyData=true` `mtx` variable will have its own memory, or if you use `copyData=false` `mtx` variable will share the memory of `img`. In either case when `mtx` is destroyed `img` won't be dangling, however it needs to be cleaned by calling release function if you want it to be destroyed. In addition, in the first case, you can release `img` before destroying `mtx`, in the latter you can't.

Note: There is no reference counting in `IplImage`.

Comment: "In either case when mtx is destroyed img will be dangling" - but not if `copyData=true`, right? Then it would have its own copy of the matrix, and only that would be destroyed, right?

Comment: @sashoalm I've updated my answer. Previous one was kind of wrong.

Comment: note, that this won't be possible in opencv3.0 any more.

Comment: @berak creating Mat instance from IplImage?

Comment: @guneykayim,  the constructor / cast operator got removed there. (they're serious about getting rid of IplImage there...)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use IplImage? 
You should stick nowadays only with cv::Mat (no cv::Mat* nor IplImage).

In addition, using IplImage*, leads to dangling pointer once your Mat is destroyed.
It would be better to use

`std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>`

or

`std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat>`

to avoid it, if strictly necessary

Comment: "Why do you use IplImage?" - I don't, I saw it used in the tutorial, and wondered about it. Besides, I can always stumble upon it in someone else's code - you know, there are things like legacy code, and one of my colleagues is using IplImage everywhere.

Comment: but IplImage is part of this "old style" API, belonging to OpenCV versions prior to 2.2. cv::Mat got increased capabilities and pointers are not used anymore, since cv::Mat frees itself memory at the end of its life: no more release() calls!

Comment: This does not answer the question, although it is technically correct.

Comment: No, this is not correct, destroying Mat would not lead dangling pointer.

Comment: @guneykayim What I meant by "correct" is the recommendation to use cv::Mat, and smart pointers if IplImage is requested somewhere.